# How can I create a vector long shadow in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shadows

I got the following made within Illustrator, but I am trying to achieve the shadow effect which is on the picture to the right of the cellphone.

[image: example image]

So far I have used the pen tool to outline where i want the shadow, and used the gradient tool with a transparent end.

However, the gradient starts at the top left, and then the gradient effect doens't work.

How can I achieve the effect on the picture to the right, within Illustrator?

Comment: See: http://vectips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/12.png

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to do this is with a blend. What you do is copy your blue background and make it black or something like that. Now copy that shape, offset it diagonally and set the opacity to 0. Then apply a blend with the specified steps to something like 100. That should get you the effect you're looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably go with Kurtis' blend suggestion, but you could achieve a similar effect with an actual drop shadow if you use a clipping mask to alter the shape.

[image: Drop shadow example]

The clipping mask is outlined in red. Duplicating the blue rounded rectangle and placing it on top (with the drop shadow removed) produced the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Using Blend is never a good idea as you'll always get "steps" in the diagonals, you should rather use the Extrude Method, detailed here: http://www.vektorgarten.de/long-shadows-with-illustrator.html

Comment: Or just use the blend method, then delete some points. Doing that relies on it being possible with the original object though.